# PowerShell Loop not continuing after exception

Tags: loops, powershell

This is my first post, I've been a long time reader of various post.

What I have to do is disable a large number of services in a large number of VM's.  I have 6-7 different enviornments to do this in  I created 2 text files//paths which I gave the variables $vmList and $serviceList.

When I run these through the different environments using (EXTERNAL IP) addresses it works in for only 1 environment.  When I try to run this with (INTERNAL IP) addresses I get the same identical exception thrown which is that it cannot find the set service (defragsvc) on the machine and then exits the loops.  However when I log into these machines they are definitely there but not started.  I am definitely lost as to why this works in 1 environment (confirmed on the machines) but fails in the others any help would be appreciated

```
     $vmList  =gc C:\PowerCli\Services\Staging_1_Defrag_Kill.txt
     $serviceList =gc C:\PowerCli\Services\ServicesKill.txt 


     ForEach ($vm in $vmList){
     ForEach ($service in $serviceList){

           write-host $vm

            Stop-service -inputobject(Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $vm)-force -confirm:$false -EA SilentlyContinue

            Set-Service -ComputerName $vm -Name $service -EA Stop -Startmode Disabled
             Write-Host "$vm : Successfully disabled the service $service" -ErrorAction  SilentlyContinue
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but rather than `-EA Stop` I would recommend `Try{Set-Service <args>;Write-Host <Message>}Catch{Write-Host "Failed to stop service on $vm" -for Red}` to better track what works and what doesn't, and not just dump the script.

Comment: Without having intimate knowledge of your networks for things like group policy settings and what not I don't think we can accurately answer this question with the information provided.

Comment: The EA stop is the cause of the terminating loop. Are you also sure you are using the correct service name? The internal names can be quite different compared to the friendly names.

Comment: Yea as per my answer below as it turned out I couldn't access service control manager remotely due to a permissions error.  I resolved this re-ran and it worked.  Go figure!  Thank you for taking the time to try to help me I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Hah, I figured it out,

As it turns out, I couldnt connect to the service control manager, it was a permissions error not a problem with the script. Lessons learned